# "Missing $ inserted " error while using algorithm2e

Tags: errors, algorithm2e

Hello Latex Community,

I'm writing an algorithm but the TEX maker is showing an error "missing $ inserted error in  the last line of the algorithm (\end{algorithm})!!! Could you please help me !!

```
     \begin{algorithm}[hbt!]
      \DontPrintSemicolon
       \caption{Double $Q$-learning algorithm pseudo-code}\label{alg2}
       \KwInput{ $\delta \in \left[ 0,1  \right]$ (discount factor), $\alpha \in 
      \left ( 0,1  \right]$ (learning rate), $\epsilon \in \left [ 0,1  \right)$ 
     (exploration rate),   $rand_{\epsilon}$, $rand_q$ (random numbers $\in \left[ 
       0,1  \right]$ generated every time step)}.  %\vspace{1mm}
              \For{every state-action pair:}{
            initialize $Q_A(s,a)$  and $Q_B(s,a)$ tables \; \Comment*[r] 
           {\footnotesize usually by zeros matrices}
                  }




              \For{every learning episode:}{
                    \While{state $ \neq $ final state}{
                      \For{each time step:}{
                         observe the current state $S_t$ \;
                      
           \eIf{$rand_{\epsilon}$ \textless  $\epsilon$}{
      $A_t =\max \limits_{a} \left[Q_A(S_t,a)+Q_B(S_t,a)\right]$  \;   \Comment*[r] 
                {\footnotesize exploitation}
            }{
               $A_t= \text{a random action}$ \;        \Comment*[r]{\footnotesize 
                                        exploration}
      }
      perform action $A_t$, observe $S_{t+1}$ and $R_{t+1}$ \;
      
      \eIf{$rand_q < 0.5$} {\Comment*[r]{\footnotesize with 0.5 probability}
      
      \begin{matrix*}[l]
         Q_A(S_t,A_t)  \gets (1-\alpha) Q_A(S_t,A_t)+ \\
           \alpha\left[R_{t+1}+\delta \max \limits_{a}Q_B(S_{t+1},\max \limits_{a}Q_A(s,a))\right]
     \end{matrix*} 
      }{
      \begin{matrix*}[l]
        Q_B(S_t,A_t)  \gets (1-\alpha) Q_B(S_t,A_t)+\\ 
          \alpha\left[R_{t+1}+\delta \max \limits_{a}Q_A(S_{t+1},\max \limits_{a}Q_B(s,a))\right] 
      \end{matrix*}
      }
        \Comment*[r]{\footnotesize $Q$ tables updating}
      $S_t \gets S_{t+1}$  \;              \Comment*

[r]{\footnotesize state updating}
          }
       }
   }
    \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us which LaTeX packages must be loaded in order to get your code to compile.

Comment: Off-topic: Is there a reason for writing `$rand_{\epsilon}$ \textless  $\epsilon$` instead of `$rand_{\epsilon}<\epsilon$`?

Comment: \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your answer. There in no reason, but i think it is the same !

Comment: Using those packages I still get an error that `\KwInput` is not defined. (Also `\Comment`.) Could you edit your code into a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that generates the error for you starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: But is the problem the matrices? Shouldn't you be starting math mode before `\begin{matrix*}` and ending it after `\end{matrix*}`?